Are there an infinite number of distinguishable time complexity classes contained in any given class?
Let $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ be a monotone increasing function.  Then, do there exist an infinite number of complexity classes below $\textsf{DTIME}(f(n))$?  That is, do we have an infinite hierarchy of form
$$
\textsf{DTIME}(1)\subsetneq \cdots \subsetneq \textsf{DTIME}(f(n))?
$$
I think the answer is obviously "yes" because we can just consider, say, $\textsf{DTIME}(n^{1/k})$ for all $k$, but I want to confirm my intuition.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_hierarchy_theorem
